# Eigenvalues of a rank-one update of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector

I have a matrix $A$ $(n\times n)$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, then I add another matrix to it as: $A+xx^\top$ where $x$ $(n\times 1)$ is a column vector.

and also $A=yy^\top$ with $y$ a $(n-1)$ rank matrix, so A is symmetric.

Is there any way to calculate the new eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $(xx^\top+yy^\top)$ using the information from the vector $x$ and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $yy^\top$？

Comment: no, you will also need information on the eigenvectors of $yy^\top$, only having information on its eigenvalues is insufficient;

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make the known conditions clear. If the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of yyT are known and x is known, can this go for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of (xxT + yyT)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $A$, you can transform to a basis where $A$ is a diagonal matrix $D$; the vector $x$ in that basis transforms to $\tilde{x}$. Then the problem is that of computing the eigenvalues of a rank-one update $D+\tilde{x}\tilde{x}^\top$ of a diagonal matrix. An efficient algorithm is given in a [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.454.9868&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Golub, page 325. Once you have the eigenvalues the eigenvectors follow directly from the [Bunch–Nielsen–Sorensen formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula)

Comment: One thing that confuses me about Golub's article(page 325) is whether there are conditions on the vector \mathbf{u} that define its positivity or negativity. I don't quite understand the discussion about the positivity and negativity of \sigma.

Comment: Golub writes the rank-one-update as $D+\sigma uu^\top$, and then considers separately the case of positive and negative $\sigma$; you can just set $\sigma=1$, and ignore the case of negative $\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. Now it is a problem to solve in reverse. If the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $(xx^\top+yy^\top)$ are known, and vector $x$ is known, can the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $yy^\top$ be obtained?

Comment: this is really the same problem; given $A=xx^\top+yy^T$, seek the eigenvalues of $A-xx^\top$ -- so this is Golub's $D+\sigma uu^\top$ with $\sigma=-1$.

Comment: for pointers to the literature on low-rank updates, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/143555/11260

Comment: Here is the new case: the added matrix is still a rank one matrix but it is $uv^\top$,where $u$ $(n\times 1)$ and $v$ $(n\times 1)$ are column vector,how can I calculate the eigenvectors of $(A+uv^\top)$ using the information from the vector $u$,$v$ and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$？(The eigenvalues could  still be calculated by the algorithm given in Golub's paper,but it seems that the Bunch-Nielsen-Sorensen formula is unable to calculate the eigenvectors).

Comment: @brant -- a new question needs a new post; one question per post, please.