# Eigenvectors of a non-symmetric rank-one update of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector

I have a matrix $A$ $(n\times n)$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, then I add another matrix to it as: $A+uv^\top$ where $u$ $(n\times 1)$ and $v$ $(n\times 1)$ are column vector. Also, $A=yy^\top$ with $y$ a $(n-1)$ rank matrix, so $A$ is symmetric.

Is there any way to calculate the new eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $(uv^\top+yy^\top)$ using the information from the vector $u$,$v$ and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $yy^\top$？

(The eigenvalues could be calculated by the algorithm given in Golub's paper,but it seems that the Bunch-Nielsen-Sorensen formula is unable to calculate the eigenvectors)

Comment: follow-up question on this earlier post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/444610/11260 , which includes the reference to Golub's paper mentioned in the post

Comment: Why are some matrices uppercase and others lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the [Bunch–Nielsen–Sorensen formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunch%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Sorensen_formula), but you will need to distinguish between left and right eigenvectors. These are different, because the rank-one-update is not symmetric. So if you work in the basis where $A$ is diagonal, with elements $a_k$ on the diagonal, and the vectors $u$ and $v$ in this basis are $\tilde{u}$ and $\tilde{v}$, the $i$-th left and right eigenvectors at eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ will have elements $\tilde{u}_k/(a_k-\lambda_i)$ and $\tilde{v}_k/(a_k-\lambda_i)$.

The nonsymmetric BNS formula follows from the nonsymmetric
[Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), applied to $(A-\lambda I+uv^\top)^{-1}$.

Comment: So it is not possible to get the left eigenvector of $A+uv^\top$ directly?

Comment: Sorry I didn't express myself clearly. In fact, $A$ is an irreversible symmetric matrix of rank $(n-1)$, and the eigenvalues of $A+uv^\top$ can be considered as known conditions. What I need to know is the left eigenvector of $A+uv^\top$, not the left eigenvector and the right eigenvector separately.

Comment: certainly, these are given by the BNS formula: the left eigenvector at eigenvalue $\lambda$ in the basis where $A=\text{diag}\,(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n)$ is diagonal has elements $v_k/(a_k-\lambda)$.

Comment: The $BNS$ formula does still apply, it was me who failed to understand the derivation of the formula and the difference between the left and right eigenvectors before. Thanks again from the bottom of my heart for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\la\lambda$Here is a complete (and elementary) analysis. Without loss of generality, the matrix $A$ is diagonal, with the eigenvalues $\la_i$ on the diagonal.

Let $z\ne0$ be an eigenvector of $B:=A+uv^\top$, so that for some complex $\mu$
\begin{equation*}
    Az+cu=\mu z, \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
where $c:=v^\top z$.

If $c=0$ -- that is, if $z$ is orthogonal to $v$, then $Az=\mu z$ and hence $z$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $\mu=\la_i$ for some $i$. So, the eigenvectors of $B$ orthogonal to $v$ are precisely the eigenvectors of $A$ orthogonal to $v$, with the same eigenvalues for $B$ and $A$.

Consider now the eigenvectors $z$ of $B$ not orthogonal to $v$, so that $c\ne0$. Then, in view of \eqref{10}, for $z=(z_i)$, $u=(u_i)$, $v=(v_i)$, and all $i$ we have $\la_i z_i+cu_i=\mu z_i$, whence for all $i$
\begin{equation*}
    z_i=\frac{cu_i}{\mu-\la_i}, \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
where $\mu$ is allowed to take value $\la_i$ for some $i$ only if $u_i=0$, and then $z_i$ is allowed to take any complex value. With such an understanding of the meaning of the ratio in \eqref{20} and recalling that here $c=v^\top z\ne0$, we see that the eigenvalue $\mu$ of $B$ is found as a root of the equation
\begin{equation*}
    1=\sum_i \frac{v_i u_i}{\mu-\la_i}. 
\end{equation*}
For each $i$, the meaning of the ratio $r_i:=\dfrac{v_i u_i}{\mu-\la_i}$ in the latter display is as follows: (i) if $v_i=0$, then $r_i:=0$ and (ii) if $v_i\ne0$, then $\mu$ is allowed to take value $\la_i$ only if $u_i=0$, and then $r_i$ is allowed to take any complex value.

The above description of the eigensystem of $B$ obviously simplifies if all the $u_i$'s are nonzero.
$\quad\Box$